# Twitter OAuth fails with 'Unauthorized' error with R call

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I setup a Twitter app, and gave Read,Write permissions. I noted down the API key and secret. Then, I called setup_twitter_oauth() as follows :

```
setup_twitter_oauth("key","secret")
[1] "Using browser based authentication"
Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app,
          permission =    self$params$permission) : 
client error: (401) Unauthorized
```

As seen, the request is rejected as Unauthorized. What could be the reason? Please let me know if further information is required to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing some parameters from your call to `setup_twitter_oauth`.  There are 4 parameters which you need:

```
consumer_key    <- '...'
consumer_secret <- '...'
access_token    <- '...'
access_secret   <- '...'

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works! I was a bit confused because I was referring to the first call to setup_twitter_oauth() mentioned at:

http://geoffjentry.hexdump.org/twitteR.pdf